# Drupal 7 мета теги

Tags: drupal

Как вывести мета теги в 7-ой линейке друпала?

Answer (score 4):

Для редактирования и настройки метатeгов используйте модуль [metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) или [metatags_quick](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatags_quick)